# Capturing hive output over ssh using python

Tags: python, ssh, hive, fabric

I'm trying to automate many of my hive jobs using fabric and capture the output.  The hive jobs run on a server (that is accessed through a proxy) and I want to save the output of these hive jobs to a file on my local machine.  Currently my method is to use shell scripts to call hive through SSH and redirect output to a text file.  Here's an example:

```
ssh myserver "hive -e 'show tables;'" > myserver_results.txt
```

I'm trying to recreate something similar using python and fabric:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.gateway = 'my_proxy'
env.hosts = ['hive_server']
output = run("hive -e 'show tables;'")
print(output)
```

My issue is that the output using the shell script and using fabric are not equal.  The output from shell script will look like the following:

```
[HIVE OUTPUT]
```

Whereas the result in fabric from `print(output)` and `print(output.stdout)`  will both look like:

```
[WELCOME MESSAGE FOR THIS SERVER]
[HIVE START CONSOLE OUTPUT]
[HIVE OUTPUT]
[Time taken: 0.2 seconds, Fetched: 520 row(s)]
```

Is there an easy way to reproduce the output of my shell script using python and fabric?

EDIT:
I want to edit my original question and expand the scope.  After some more experimentation I think Fabric won't be able to easily capture output in the way that I want.  So I pose the question, is there a way to use python to run hive scripts over SSH and capture the hive output?

Here is a summary of requirements:

1. The output MUST match the contents of the file when I do: `ssh myserver "hive -e 'show tables;'" > myserver_results.txt`
2. Streaming output of hive messages/progress like I would if I ran the above command in shell
3. Easy setup to work with SSH and proxy server without necessarily needing to depend on having setup ssh config.

From my experimentation I have tried using the following python libraries: paramiko, fabric, plumbum, sarge.

I think Fabric is the closest and satisfies (2), (3).  Sarge appears to satisfy (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting more with Fabric I can come very close to mimicking the output from `ssh myserver "hive -e 'show tables;'" > myserver_results.txt`.  Here are a few ways I've tried:

1. `run("hive -e 'show tables;' 2>/dev/null")`: this will redirect hive's stderr messages to null and the final output given back by fabric will not include it.  This doesn't entirely work because it also suppresses hive's progress messages -- for long jobs you can never be sure if the job is running correctly or has stalled.
2. Set `env.combine_stderr = False` and `env.always_use_pty = False` and `run` as normal.  From the documentation this will turn pseudo terminal off making it difficult to interact but in running a hive job appears to not be that big of a deal.  Further, with both of these options it allows for a distinct stdout and stderr.  However, this still doesn't get rid of the welcome message from the server before hive starts.
3. `output = run("hive -e 'show tables;' > temp_file.txt")`. Pipe the output to a file on the server and simply don't even try dealing with the streaming output returned from fabric.  This file can be written to the server's `/tmp` and can be copied to local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you’re getting a login banner, but this might have some explanation for how to suppress it:  https://serverfault.com/questions/66986/suppressing-ssh-banner-from-openssh-client/67006  You can also use `tail` and `head` to massage your output and, of course, you can always manipulate the results of `stdout` in memory.  So I would do something like this

```
output = run(
    "hive -e 'show tables;' "
    "| head -n -1 "
    "| tail -n -3")
# where 3 is the number of lines you want to skip at the beginning
```

While I am not a hive expert, there are several settings you can also set in the `.hiverc` file that can change the format of the output.

Comment: I'm confused as well, when I run the commands through SSH I see the server welcome message in the terminal but it doesn't get piped to the text file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, the head/tail limit the hive output but the server message and hive start/end messages still show up